# Как удалить и сместить элемент в динамическом массиве?

Tags: c

Нужно удалить из массива элементы, соседние с первым минимальным элементом. Подскажите как удалить и сдвинуть их?

Comment: Надо просто сдвинуть элементы. Никакого другого "удалить" в массиве быть не может.

Comment: `memmove(p,p+1,sizeof(T)*n)` - сдвигает содержимое памяти. *Заходи с примером, если что.*

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `memmove`:

```c
int delete_elem(int arr[], size_t n, size_t idx)
{
    size_t from_idx = idx + 1;
    size_t sz = (n - from_idx) * sizeof(int);
    memmove(&arr[idx], &arr[from_idx], sz);

    return n - 1;
}
```

*IDEOne*: https://ideone.com/c83jLz.