# Требуется исключить из массива mas1 элементы, номера которых совпадают с элементами mas2. Пример: mas1={1,2,3,4,5,6} mas2={2,3,8} => mas1={1,2,5}

Tags: c++

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <locale.h>
 #include <string.h>
 int main()
 { 
 int n=7, m=4,mas1[100],mas2[100],i,j,k,count;
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  scanf("%d",&mas1[i]);
 for(j=0;j<m;j++)
  scanf("%d",&mas2[j]);

 for(int j = 0; j < m-1; j)
 {
    for(int k = 0; k< m-j-1; k++)
    {
        if(mas2[k] < mas2[k+1])
        {

            int temp = mas2[k];
            mas2[k] = mas2[k+1];
            mas2[k+1] = temp;
        }
    }
 }
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   if (i==mas2[j])
  {
       mas1[i] = mas1[i + 1];
  }    
    i=i-1;
    count++;
  for(i=0;i<n-count;i++)
   printf("%d",mas1[i]);
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Во-первых, непонятно, в чем у вас проблема. Во-вторых: массивы отсортированы? Точнее, массив mas2?

Comment: нет,программа выводит не то

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1044571/180092.

Comment: Советую отсортировать, тогда Вам можно будет избавиться от цикла по j, что позволит ускорить программу. Что касается неправильной работы... Как минимум, Вы теряете последний элемент в самом внутреннем цикле, при копирования элементов со старшими индексами.

Comment: @Ainar-G Это все же не совсем дубликат. Там есть сдвиг элементов, но нет проверки массива индексов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работает только если в массиве `mas1` только положительные числа. Как вариант можно присваивать вместо -1, какое-нибудь другое огромное число.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n, m;
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &m);

    int mas1[n], ind;

    for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &mas1[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0; i < m; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &ind);

        if(ind >= 0 && ind < n)
            mas1[ind] = -1;
    }

    for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        if(mas1[i] != -1) printf("%d ", mas1[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Неплохой вариант... Только лучше все же не ограничиваться случаем тупо вывода массива пользователю, а сделать нормальный поправленный массив. То есть не ограничиваться заменой на  -1 или еще что, а организовать сдвиг элементов.

Comment: сдвиг элементов - достаточно прожорливая операция...

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @ЭльдарЮсупжанов, конечно. И для учебного задания Ваш вариант может подойти. При условии, что преподаватель не скажет что-то типа: "Надо было сформировать скорректированный массив, а не просто вывести на экран его элементы". Кстати, про ввод он может сказать то же самое.

Comment: да, скорее всего надо сортировкой сделать,сейчас попробую

Comment: вам нужно удалять не нужные элементы? Если так то, после удаления индексы будут съезжать

Comment: @jilo, только не сортируйте первый массив. Иначе Вы измените расположение элементов, индексы перестанут соответствовать тому, что указано во втором массиве, и Вы получите неверный результат

Comment: можете подсказать почему  не работает?

Comment: Что вы хотите сделать? Мой код не подходит?

Comment: мне нужно сделать то же самое, только изменяя массив через сдвиг

Comment: можно отсортировать массив после вывода

Comment: я не совсем понимаю вас

Comment: Вы хотите в конце получить массив без лишних элементов?

Comment: Вы хотите в конце получить массив без лишних элементов? да